# How to convert String List to String in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, converters

I need to convert `List<String>` into a `String` in the dart.

I want to extract the value of the list from preferences. I have tried this implementation but it is only giving me the last value.

```
Future<List<String>> services = SharedPrefSignUp.getSelectedServices();
services.then((onValue){
  List<String>servicesList=onValue;
  selectServicesText=servicesList.join(",");
});
```

Comment: you can iterate a list and concatenate items with stringbuffer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can iterate list and concatenate values with StringBuffer

```dart
  var list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  var concatenate = StringBuffer();

  list.forEach((item){
    concatenate.write(item);
  });

  print(concatenate); // displays 'onetwothree'

  }
```

Answer (score 102):

if you know you have `List<String>` then you can use `join()` function provided by a flutter.

```
    var list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    var stringList = list.join("");
    print(stringList); //Prints "onetwothree"
```

Simple and short. ;)

And you can use it like this:

```
 List<String> servicesList = ["one", "Two", "Thee"]; 
 print(servicesList.join(""));
```

Comment: How can I make it clickable for each one of them?

Answer (score 21):

You can use [reduce](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/reduce.html) method on a list like that:

```dart
List<String> list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
final string = list.reduce((value, element) => value + ',' + element);

// For your example:
List<String> servicesList = await SharedPrefSignUp.getSelectedServices();
selectServicesText = servicesList.reduce((value, element) => value + ',' + element);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when using a list of class (List<ClassName> classList) The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'ClassName'.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone wants to concatenate specific member strings in a list of objects : here is a way to do the same-

```
   string commaSeparatedNames=return listOfObjectsWithNameAttribute
      .map((item) => item.name)
      .toList()
      .join(",");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 print(list.toString().replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']',''))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you need just first word to be highlighted use this

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextHighlight extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  TextHighlight({
    required this.text,
  });

  @override
  State<TextHighlight> createState() => _textHighlightState();
}

class _textHighlightState extends State<TextHighlight> {
  String first = '';

  List<String> allText = [];
  List<String> newText = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    first = widget.text.split(' ').first;
    allText = widget.text.split(' ')..removeAt(0);

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(text: first+' ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 17)),
          TextSpan(text: allText.join(' ').toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@nivia360 its work for me!

The problem is cant eliminate the bracket to the list of array.
this code `movie.tags.toString(),`
Return this list whit brackets

`[Adventure, Fantasy, Action]`

I soved how the @nivia360 propouse usingn

```
movie.tags.toString().replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', ''),
```

[Problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Az7.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUAfD.png)