# Remove postalcode from string

Tags: flutter, dart

How to remove numbers and "-" sign from String using regExp?

I have string: "4502-42 something" and I just want to have only "something".

Edit:

Strings are different eg:
"2232-233 Something",
"SomethingElse",
"223-4 SomethingElseElse" etc.

We can say that I want to remove everything which is on front including space.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove everything up to &  including the (first) space?

Comment: The thing is that some strings are good, and some contains code and space
(eg: "1723-243 SomeCity" and "AnotherCity")
So, yes we can say that. Remove all including first space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. It is also more safe than just saying "skip everything up to first space" since the city name could contain spaces.

```
void main() {
  final input = [
    "2232-233 Something",
    "SomethingElse",
    "223-4 SomethingElseElse",
    "223-4 SomethingElseElse Else"
  ];

  input
      .map((string) => string.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'\d*-\d* '), ''))
      .forEach(print);
  // Something
  // SomethingElse
  // SomethingElseElse
  // SomethingElseElse Else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split method and then access strings after space.

```
  var string = "Hello world!";
  List<String> strings = string.split(" ");
  var res = strings.where((element) => element != strings.first);
```

`input : Hello world!`

`output : world!`

Comment: This works if 'something' doesn't have space in it, But if it does, no probm! Use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443354/how-to-convert-string-list-to-string-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

@julemand101 - thank's a lot ;)

I've change it a little bit and my solution is:

```
 static String removeCode(String str) =>
      str.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'\d*-\d* '), '');
```

I'm just calling this method on string I want to format and it's looks like this:

```
model.city.isSafe()
      ? Formatter.removeCode(model.city)
      : "No info",
```

*isSafe is a method which is checking is not null/empty string etc.