# How to cast list to string and save it's quotes marks?

Tags: dart

I have list:

```
List list = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
```

I need to get string:

```
"['aa', 'bb', 'cc']"
```

with `.toString()` I am getting:

```
[aa, bb, cc]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56443354/2804581

Answer (score 2):

```
List list = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
var str = '"${list.map((s) => "'$s'").toList()}"';
```

or

```
var str = '"[\'' + list.join("', '") + '\']"';
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [`jsonEncode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) from `dart:convert`.
It means your strings will use `"` instead of `'` for quoting, and won't have pretty spaces after the comma, but it's also much simpler and safer than trying to create the strings yourself, and it means you can read the list back using [`jsonDecode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html).

Very conveniently, JSON list and string values look just like Dart list and string literals. It also takes care of escaping any embedded `"` or `\` characters you might have in the strings.

```dart
var myList = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
var string = jsonEncode(myList);
print(string); // ["aa","bb","cc"]
```

Alternatively, only use `jsonEncode` on the strings themselves:

```dart
var string2 = [for (var s in myList) jsonEncode(s)].toString();
print(string); // ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
```

If you want `'` quoted strings, then it is probably safer to do:

```dart
String myStringEncode(String content) =>
  "'${content.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r"[\\']"), (m) => "\\${m[0]}")}'";
var string3 = [for (var s in myList) myStringEncode(s)].toString();
print(string3); // ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Comment: Exactly this. Should an accepted answer. Instead of reinventing the wheel and self-writing such utility code.